# Sending Multipart json String with Jersey 2

Tags: java, json, rest, multipart, jersey-client

I want to write a Java REST Client that uploads a json String. I have a description about the webservice and a C++ Code but that doesn't help me. Unfortunately, the solutions I found online doesn't work for me.
The description of the webservice states that have to use MultiPart.

- MultiPart

  - ContentDispositionHeader: form-data name = "\ObjectInfo"\

    - some Info
    - some more Info
    - ....
  - ContentDispositionHeader:  form-data name = filename

    - File multipart data

This description doesn't help me very much. I'm struggeling with creating the MultiPart, I get a very long exception stack when trying to post the data. The code snippet is es follows:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .build();
WebTarget target = client.target(baseUri + "/FileHandler?projectRecId="+projectRecId+"&versionRecId="+versionRecId+"&updateSchedules=true");

MultivaluedMap<String, String> info = new MultivaluedHashMap<String, String>();
info.add("FileTypeRecId", scheduleGuid);
info.add("CreatedUpdatedBy", user);
info.add("actualFileName", scheduleFileName);
info.add("MetaData","PROJECTID:" + projektIdFromJson + ";EINBAUDATUM:" + einbaudatumFromJson);

MultiPart infoPart = new MultiPart();
infoPart.contentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("ObjectInfo").build());
infoPart.bodyPart(new BodyPart().entity(info));

MultiPart filePart = new MultiPart();
filePart.contentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name(scheduleFileName).build());
filePart.bodyPart(scheduleJson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);

MultiPart multiPartEntity = new MultiPart()
    .bodyPart(infoPart)
    .bodyPart(filePart);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    .header("Authorization", "xxx")
    .post(Entity.entity(multiPartEntity, multiPartEntity.getMediaType()));
```

Exception stars with:

```
Aug 19, 2015 10:37:14 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNUNG: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for     [org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide]     with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParsingException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException
...

MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide
contracts={javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader}
scope=javax.inject.Singleton
qualifiers={org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Custom}
descriptorType=CLASS
descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
metadata=
rank=0
loader=null
proxiable=null
proxyForSameScope=null
analysisName=null
id=70
locatorId=1
identityHashCode=1763344271
reified=false)
...
```

There are more of these HK2 Errors, I can provide the whole message of needed.

I have now clue what i did wrong, does anybody of you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the following jars in your project.

```
1. mimepull.jar
2. jersey-multipart.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, the mimepull.jar was missing. I accidently added the mimepull-javadoc.jar instead..

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your problem please mark appropriately